# How do I get the innerXml or outerXml in JavaScript and FireFox

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox

When using IE, the following works -

```
 alert("XML Root IE: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.tagName); // ok
 alert("Xml: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.xml);             // ok
```

but for FireFox, the functions xml,innerxml,outerxml, are all undefined.

```
   alert("tagName: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.tagName);  // ok
   alert("Xml Content: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.xml);  // undefined
   alert("Xml innerxml: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.innerxml);  // undefined
   alert("Xml outerxml: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.outerxml);  // undefined
```

How do I get the actual XML on FireFox?
(I know I read the XML correctly because "documentElement.tagName" returns correct on both IE and FF)

Thanks,

Atara

EDIT: Here is the relevant FF code:

```
    var xmlDoc;

function fLoadXml() {
  // alert("fLoadXml()");
  if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
    fLoadXmlIE()
  } else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) { // FF
    fLoadXmlFF()
  }
}

function fLoadXmlFF() {
   // alert("fLoadXmlFF()");
   xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("","",null) ;
   xmlDoc.async = false;
   xmlDoc.onload = fReadXmlFF;
   var loaded = xmlDoc.load("myFile.xml");
   alert("loaded: " + loaded);
}

function fReadXmlFF() {
   alert("fReadXmlFF()");
   alert("tagName: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.tagName);
   alert("Xml Content: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.xml);  // undefined
   alert("Xml innerxml: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.innerxml);  // undefined
   alert("Xml outerxml: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.outerxml);  // undefined

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it in -
http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/convert-xml-document-to-string-in-javascript

Solution:

```
function fReadXmlFF() {
   alert("tagName: " + xmlDoc.documentElement.tagName);  // ok
   strXml = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlDoc); // ok
   . . .
```

Comment: +1 Works great in FF and Chrome. FYI - this does not work in IE. You can test if ActiveXObject is defined (if true, use `.xml`) if you want to provide cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

xml is an IE only property, try something else like ChildNodes and NodeValue, check it out here: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_document.asp

Comment: none of these functions seems to return the whole XML as string. What do I miss?